# C++ Разбиение строки на вектор слов

Tags: c++

Есть файл со строками разной длины. Слова в котором, разделены запятыми.
Нужно считать эти слова в двумерный вектор.

Написал такой код, но при исполнении, вектор остаеться пустым

```
vector<vector<string> > features;
        string str, item;
        int i = 0;

        while(file)
        {
            getline(file, str);
            stringstream ss(str);

            while(getline(ss, item, ','))
                features[i].push_back(item);

            i++;
        }
```

Подскажите в чем проблема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

когда Вы обращаетесь вот так `features[i].push_back(item);`, то Вы обращаетесь к несуществующему элементу. То, что вектор остался пустым - просто повезло. А могло и упасть или ещё что то.

То есть, как минимум, нужно переписать так

```
vector<vector<string> > features;
string str, item;
int i = 0;
while(file)
{
    features.push_back(vector<string>()); // это ключевая строка
    getline(file, str);
    stringstream ss(str);
    while(getline(ss, item, ','))
        features[i].push_back(item);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Нехорошо - `while(file)` сработает только после того, как (непроверяемый вами) `getline` сбойнет.

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте про `while(file)` - оно сработает только *после* неудачного чтения.

Примерно так:

```
vector<vector<string>> features;
string str, item;

while(getline(file, str))
{
    stringstream ss(str);
    vector<string> vs;
    while(getline(ss, item, ','))
        vs.push_back(item);
    if (vs.size()) features.push_back(vs);
}
```

Вы добавляете новый вектор со словами в `features` только по факту, если что-то считано.